# No wireless in Archlinux Gnome3

Tags: arch-linux, gnome3, wifi

Successfully installed Gnome3 on archlinux (not the fallback mode).

EDIT: My wired internet connection works fine.

However, I can't see the network icon (or wireless networks) in the tray. When I open `Network Connections` from Gnome3 the Wired and Wireless tabs are empty.

I think I tried everything I could think of:

1. putting `network-manager` in `DAEMONS` in `rc.conf` and relogging, but nothing happens.
2. installing `network-manager-applet`
3. Googling, but [threads](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=116715) like these leave much to be desired.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Some information about your wireless card and firmware would help diagnose your issue. Have you tried setting it up manually as per the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless)?

Comment: So what's *exactly* the issue you are trying to address? That the tool you used to use in order to check networking status and set up new connections is not showing up anymore, or that the network device is not working anymore? In case you, yourself, are not sure, please check first if the network device is being detected (kernel log, `dmesg`; PCI and USB device lists `lspci`, `lsusb`; network device lists `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`). Problems with a GUI tool not showing the right thing are completely different from lack of device support.

Comment: @jasonwryan I followed the wiki (my card is `Intel Ultimate-N 5300` ) - but there is no actual "setup" in it. The drivers for my chipset "have been supported since kernel 2.6.27".

Comment: @njsg My wired internet works, but my wireless - I don't know how to set-it up. The Gnome's Network Connections Dialog shows no wireless OR wired connections. I'll run the commands you provided when I get home, thank you.

Comment: @njsg When running `lspci` I can see my wireless `Intel Corporation Ultimate N Wifi Link 5300` in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always, the problem was with no finishing the reading of documentation.

I needed to actually run *NetworkManager* (gnome automatically picks it up), and disable archlinux's `network` daemon. It's all here:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager#Configuration

NOTE: You can start daemon manually by running:

```
sudo /etc/rc.d/networkmanager
```